# How do I delete any temporary files(created during session) on abrupt end of the server?

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.5.5.

I have a view that allows user to upload a huge excel file into the database. For this first I store the uploaded file in the `/tmp/` folder along with a lock file to disallow concurrent access to the DB.

Now assuming the user is in the middle of the uploading (which takes up to 15 minutes), if the server abruptly ends (for any reason), how do I catch this exception so that I can delete all the temporary files?

Comment: The server will automatically clean out `/tmp` (if that is the real directory). You have two bigger issues - the first is you have a from that is taking 15 minutes(!) to send a response; and the second is you are using lock files(?) to manage database access. You need to fix both of these issues otherwise you'll have more problems down the line.

Comment: This is the backend part which just allows an admin to upload data into the DB. I'll work on those suggestions, thanks!

But the server does not delete those files automatically , I checked. Is there any way that I can catch this sort of an exception so that I can manually delete the files ?

Comment: I guess I was looking for some Http exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> Now assuming the user is in the middle of the uploading (which takes
>   up to 15 minutes), if the server abruptly ends (for any reason), how
>   do I catch this exception so that I can delete all the temporary
>   files?

You will not get this type of exception at your application, because your application will have already timed out (that's the actual error).

Your server should automatically be clearing out `/tmp`, if it isn't then you need to fix that, or you'll quickly run out of disk space.

To solve this problem, you need to separate the uploading of the Excel file from the page that is displaying the form, so your application doesn't keep the client waiting for a response. Use something like [`django-sticky-uploads`](http://django-sticky-uploads.readthedocs.org/en/v0.2.X/start.html) which will upload your file in the background.

You might also want to consider using [`celery`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) which is a way to run your code in the 'background' so that it doesn't make the user wait for a response. This would be useful if the processing of the file takes a long time (anything longer than 30 seconds).

Finally - you might want to use [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#transactions) to make sure your database is in a clean state should anything happen while processing the Excel file.

Comment: Thanks I managed to use celery to run the code in the background like you suggested and looked into sticky-uploads as well. And I managed to find a way around the deletion problem using transaction exceptions that Django throws.